# PHP CURL post data not redirect to action URL

Tags: php, curl, post

I have some problem with CURL to post data to URL. It not redirect to the action URL which I post the data. I have `index.php` file contains the CURL code and `test.php` which receive the post data. This is my `index.php`:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost/curl/test.php';

$myvars = 'BASKET=123&AMOUNT=15000000';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );

?>
```

And this is my `test.php`:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['BASKET'];
?>
```

When I'm trying to load `index.php` file I want redirect to the `test.php` and display the data but the problem is I'm still on the `index.php` page and not jump to `test.php` file. When I'm try use HTML Form it was fine but in this case I cannot use HTML Form because the data which I post is not from form input. Please anybody know how to that please help me. Thank you before.

Comment: cURL does not work that way. Would be best if you just create a hidden HTML form and auto post it using JavaScript.

Comment: @Vlam Could you give me some example please ?

Comment: @smith Thank you that the answer of my problem.